# Can't deploy my ionic app on real device using "Type-C" cable

Tags: deployment, usb, usb-debugging

I've created an Ionic app. Now I'm trying to deploy it on real time device (LG G-6).

My **developer mode** and **USB debugging** is enabled. But my cable is just charging my phone. No media transfer appears. So, I can't deploy my app.

Does Type-C cable only charge Phone? Or I've to change my USB cable?

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your cable to a Data+Charge type (still usb-c)

Comment: can u suggest any other way?

Comment: unfortunately, no. usb connector has four pins: Pin 1 - VBUS (+5 V), Pin 2 Data-, Pin 3 Data+, Pin 4 Ground. your cable only has pin 1 and 4 connected without the 2 and 3 (unless something is very wrong at the computer)